# Ray-tracing and CUDA

Tags: cuda, raytracing, raycasting, pycuda

I have a ray-tracing model where I fire 20k rays against a mesh object with ~100k triangular faces.

To calculate coordinates of intersection point I wrote this function based on Moller-trumbore algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm):

```
void MT_intersection(std::vector<double> origin, std::vector<double> dir, std::vector<double> v0, std::vector<double> v1, std::vector<double> v2, std::vector<double> &int_point) {
    double eps = 0.0000001;
    std::vector<double> E1(3);
    std::vector<double> E2(3);
    std::vector<double> s(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        E1[i] = v1[i] - v0[i];
        E2[i] = v2[i] - v0[i];
        s[i] = origin[i] - v0[i];
    }
    std::vector<double> h(3);
    h[0] = dir[1] * E2[2] - dir[2] * E2[1];
    h[1] = -(dir[0] * E2[2] - dir[2] * E2[0]);
    h[2] = dir[0] * E2[1] - dir[1] * E2[0];
    double a;
    a = E1[0] * h[0] + E1[1] * h[1] + E1[2] * h[2];
    if (a > -eps && a < eps) {
        int_point[0] = false;
    }
    else {
        double f = 1 / a;
        double u;
        u = f * (s[0] * h[0] + s[1] * h[1] + s[2] * h[2]);
        if (u < 0 || u > 1) {
            int_point[0] = false;
        }
        else {
            std::vector<double> q(3);
            q[0] = s[1] * E1[2] - s[2] * E1[1];
            q[1] = -(s[0] * E1[2] - s[2] * E1[0]);
            q[2] = s[0] * E1[1] - s[1] * E1[0];
            double v;
            v = f * (dir[0] * q[0] + dir[1] * q[1] + dir[2] * q[2]);
            if (v < 0 || (u + v)>1) {
                int_point[0] = false;
            }
            else {
                double t;
                t = f * (E2[0] * q[0] + E2[1] * q[1] + E2[2] * q[2]);
                if (t > eps) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        int_point[i] = origin[i] + dir[i] * t;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I give as input the origin and the direction of my ray and 3 vectors with triangles vertices coordinates (v0,v1,v2).

Then I use this function in a for loop with ~100k (number of triangles) repetitions inside another for loop with 20k (number of rays) repetitions.

Since this code is very slow (it takes approx 2 days and a half to calculate everything), I want to run it in parallel with Cuda, hoping to reduce this time.
Since I'm working with Python, I'm using PyCuda and I tried to write a C kernel with my "MT_intersection" function:

```
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy as np
from stl import mesh

my_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('sfera1.stl')
n = my_mesh.normals
v0 = my_mesh.v0
v1 = my_mesh.v1
v2 = my_mesh.v2

mod = SourceModule("""
    #include <math.h>
    //#include <vector>
  __global__ void intersect(float *origin,float *dir,float *v0,float *v1,float *v2,float *int_point_real)
  {
    using namespace std;
    //#include <vector>
    //#include <math.h>
    int idx = threadIdx.x;
    //a[idx] *= 2;
    int count = 0;

    //std::vector<double> v0_current(3);
    float v0_current[3];
    float v1_current[3];
    float v2_current[3];
    float dir_current[3] = {dir[idx][0],dir[idx][1],dir[idx][2]}; 
    //std::vector<double> v1_current(3);
    //std::vector<double> v2_current(3);
    float int_point[3];
    //std::vector<float> int_point(3);
    //std::vector<std::vector<float>> int_pointS;
    float int_pointS[2][3];
    //std::vector<std::vector<double>> int_point;
    //std::vector<int> int_faces;
    int int_faces[2];
    float dist[2];
    //std::vector<float> dist;
    int n_tri = 960;

    for(int i = 0; i<n_tri; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<3; j++){
            v0_current[j] = v0[i][j];
            v1_current[j] = v1[i][j];
            v2_current[j] = v2[i][j];
        }
        double eps = 0.0000001;
        //std::vector<float> E1(3);
        float E1[3];
        //std::vector<float> E2(3);
        float E2[3];
        //std::vector<float> s(3);
        float s[3];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            E1[j] = v1_current[j] - v0_current[j];
            E2[j] = v2_current[j] - v0_current[j];
            s[j] = origin[j] - v0_current[j];
        }
        //std::vector<float> h(3);
        float h[3];
        h[0] = dir[1] * E2[2] - dir[2] * E2[1];
        h[1] = -(dir[0] * E2[2] - dir[2] * E2[0]);
        h[2] = dir[0] * E2[1] - dir[1] * E2[0];
        float a;
        a = E1[0] * h[0] + E1[1] * h[1] + E1[2] * h[2];
        if (a > -eps && a < eps) {
            int_point[0] = false;
            //return false;
        }
        else {
            double f = 1 / a;
            float u;
            u = f * (s[0] * h[0] + s[1] * h[1] + s[2] * h[2]);
            if (u < 0 || u > 1) {
                int_point[0] = false;
                //return false;
            }
            else {
                //std::vector<float> q(3);
                float q[3];
                q[0] = s[1] * E1[2] - s[2] * E1[1];
                q[1] = -(s[0] * E1[2] - s[2] * E1[0]);
                q[2] = s[0] * E1[1] - s[1] * E1[0];
                float v;
                v = f * (dir[0] * q[0] + dir[1] * q[1] + dir[2] * q[2]);
                if (v < 0 || (u + v)>1) {
                    int_point[0] = false;
                    //return false;
                }
                else {
                    float t;
                    t = f * (E2[0] * q[0] + E2[1] * q[1] + E2[2] * q[2]);
                    if (t > eps) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                            int_point[j] = origin[j] + dir_current[j] * t;
                        }
                        //return t;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (int_point[0] != false) {
            count = count+1;
            //int_faces.push_back(i);
            int_faces[count-1] = i;
            //dist.push_back(sqrt(pow((origin[0] - int_point[0]), 2) + pow((origin[1] - int_point[1]), 2) + pow((origin[2] - int_point[2]), 2)));
            //dist.push_back(x);
            dist[count-1] = sqrt(pow((origin[0] - int_point[0]), 2) + pow((origin[1] - int_point[1]), 2) + pow((origin[2] - int_point[2]), 2));
            //int_pointS.push_back(int_point);
            for (int j = 0; j<3; j++) {
                int_pointS[count-1][j] = int_point[j];
            }
        } 
    }
    double min = dist[0];
    int ind_min = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < int_pointS.size(); i++){
        if (min > dist[i]) {
            min = dist[i];
            ind_min = i;
        }
    }
    //dist_real[Idx] = dist[ind_min];
    //int_point_real_x[Idx] = int_pointS[ind_min][0];
    //int_point_real_y[Idx] = int_pointS[ind_min][1];
    //int_point_real_z[Idx] = int_pointS[ind_min][2];
    int_point_real[Idx][0] = int_pointS[ind_min][0];
    int_point_real[Idx][1] = int_pointS[ind_min][1];
    int_point_real[Idx][2] = int_pointS[ind_min][2];
}
  """)

origin = np.asarray([1, 1, 1]).astype(np.float32)
direction = np.ones((100, 3)).astype(np.float32)
int_point_real = np.zeros((100, 3)).astype(np.float32)

intersect = mod.get_function("intersect")
intersect(drv.In(origin), drv.In(direction), drv.In(v0), drv.In(v1), drv.In(v2), drv.Out(int_point_real), block=(512,1,1), grid=(64,1,1))
```

My idea is to run the 20k rays in parallel.
This Python script is giving me different errors:

> kernel.cu(18): error: expression must have pointer-to-object type
>
> kernel.cu(18): error: expression must have pointer-to-object type
>
> kernel.cu(18): error: expression must have pointer-to-object type
>
> kernel.cu(34): error: expression must have pointer-to-object type
>
> kernel.cu(35): error: expression must have pointer-to-object type
>
> kernel.cu(36): error: expression must have pointer-to-object type
>
> kernel.cu(108): error: expression must have class type
>
> kernel.cu(118): error: expression must have pointer-to-object type
>
> kernel.cu(119): error: expression must have pointer-to-object type
>
> kernel.cu(120): error: expression must have pointer-to-object type
>
> kernel.cu(27): warning: variable "int_faces" was set but never used
>
> 10 errors detected in the compilation of
>   "C:/Users/20180781/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_00000d44_00000000-10_kernel.cpp1.ii".
>   ]

Any idea why?

Does anyone know a smarter and more efficient way to calculate the intersection point when I have a lot of rays and a lot of faces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems all the errors are reported for lines where you try to double-index things. The line numbering is a little off, but from the warning `kernel.cu(27): warning: variable "int_faces" was set but never used` it can be deduced that the first few error messages refer to the following lines:

```
float dir_current[3] = {dir[idx][0],dir[idx][1],dir[idx][2]};
```

[...]

```
v0_current[j] = v0[i][j];
v1_current[j] = v1[i][j];
v2_current[j] = v2[i][j];
```

And it makes sense, because  `dir`, `v0`, `v1`, and `v2` are all defined as `float *`. Which is just a float pointer. You can index it once like `dir[idx]`, yielding a float, but it doesn't make sense to index it (a mere float) again, like `dir[idx][0]`.

After this point point, the line numbers are off again, but accepting my hypothesis, it can be assumed that these are the last 3 problematic lines:

```
int_point_real[Idx][0] = int_pointS[ind_min][0];
int_point_real[Idx][1] = int_pointS[ind_min][1];
int_point_real[Idx][2] = int_pointS[ind_min][2];
```

And indeed, int_point_real is also just a pointer to a float.
Also, notice how although `int_pointS` is referenced in several other lines, there are no errors reported for them, because **that** variable is correctly declared as a two-dimensional array (which can be indexed twice).